# How to add javascript inside a modal window to play videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app where users can upload and play videos. Now, I have a preview modal window which allows users to click on a clip, and a modal pops up in which they can play the clip.

At the moment though, the modal just has a thumbnail of the clip like so:

```
$('#myModal .my-profiletxt').html('<%= @clip.film.name %>');
$('.qpcliptitle').html('<%= @clip.name %>');
$('.qpdesc').html('<%= @clip.description %>');
$('.qptaglist').html('<%= @clip_tags %>')
$('#myModal .queuepagevideo').html('<%= image_tag(@clip.thumbnail.url(:large)) %>');
$('#myModal .qpposter').html('<%= image_tag(@clip.film.poster.url(:medium)) %>');
$('.qpimages').html('<%= j(rating_for @clip, "rating") %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

How can I add my javascript video player in the place of the thumbnail so users can preview and play clips in the modal?

Here is the JS video player code which works outside of the modal:

```
 <div class="video-img">
        <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/Nu3Cav_oEeKU_RIxOUCPzg.js"></script>
        <div id='my-video<%= @clip.video.id %>'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('my-video<%= @clip.video.id %>').setup({
                playlist: [{
                        image: "<%= @clip.video.thumbnail_url %>",
                        sources: [
                            { file: "<%= video_url(@clip.video.remote_id, :smil) %>" },
                            { file: "<%= video_url(@clip.video.remote_id, :m3u8) %>" }
                        ]
                    }],
                primary: "flash",
                width: '100%',
                height: '350',
                rtmp: {
                        bufferlength: 7
                    }
            });
        </script>
        <%#= image_tag('video-img.jpg') %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help here would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're using Bootstrap's modal, which has a `show.bs.modal` event that fires right before the Modal is displayed. You can hook into this and then execute further javascript from the callback function.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    //execute setup function within this
});
```

I'm sure there are some dynamic arguments you'll need to pass to get the video in question, so it's probably best to use `data-video="<%= @clip.video.id %>"` so that you can store reference to the video ID within this. You'll probably need more than just that one data attribute to store reference to the thumbnail id, etc...Then in your click function, you can extract this data.